# Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output - while installing turtle through pip

Tags: python, linux, terminal, pip

I am trying to download turtle on a (Linux) device I usually use through pip. However when run I get the error (sorry it is so very very long):

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qx1dkmxw/turtle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qx1dkmxw/turtle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-qx1dkmxw/turtle/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qx1dkmxw/turtle/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-qx1dkmxw/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: you have t provide your code as well

Comment: what do you mean by **turtle**?

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/turtle/ Version 0.0.2, latest release was in 2009. The code is obviously for Python 2.

Advice: Try Python 2.7. Or forget about the package.

*Upd*. There is module [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html) in the standard library. It's probably what you want. You don't need to install it, it should already be there with the stdlib.

Comment: so for Python 3.8 is it not possible?

Comment: @RamaCan There is module [`turtle`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html) in the standard library. It's probably what you want.

Comment: @RamaCan You don't need to install it, it should already be there with the stdlib.